# How to get details of user activity for CRUD operation using Eventlogs

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, event, eventlogfile

I want to track activity of user using eventlogs object, it has many event types where we can track activity like Apex Execution, Trigger Execution, Page View details.

But i am unable to find event type which shows activity of record update, delete and edit.

Could someone please help me get the details of record specific logs?

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: So do you need information to the level of which record he inserted/updated/deleted of just to the level of operation/objectname information?

Comment: Yes, i want this information only.

Answer (score 0):

Check event log type [API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_api.htm) it shows the information of user/object/operation information. Below is a sample set of fields it shows but check the link for all fields that are available as part of this event type.

Below is a sample of how the information looks

[image]